# How can I prevent an onClick event or prevent a function from executing during a set period of time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I am using React and [iTyped](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ityped), I have a typing animation which lasts about 20 seconds. I want to have a functionality that after the animation is finished, it can be restarted with a click.

```
const typedCaller = () => {

    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      backDelay: 1500,
      typeSpeed: 110,
      backSpeed: 75,
      loop: false,
      strings: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
      
    })
  }
    
  

  const typedCaller2 = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      loop: false,
      startDelay: 1,
      backDelay: 1,
      strings: [' ', ' ']
    })
  }

  const typedCaller4 = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      loop: false,

      backSpeed: 75,
      strings: [' ', ' ']
    })
  }

  const typedCaller3 = () => {
    init(textRef.current, {
      showCursor: false,
      backDelay: 1500,
      typeSpeed: 110,
      backSpeed: 75,
      loop: false,
      strings: ['hi', 'hello', 'goodbye']
    })
  }

  const typedFun = () => {
    typedCaller2();
    setTimeout(() => {
      typedCaller3();
    }, 1000);
  }


  const textRef = useRef();

  

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      typedCaller4();
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      typedCaller();
    }, 5000);
    
  },[])

return(
  <Box>
    <Description className='SubText' onClick={typedFun} sx={{height: '30px', paddingBottom: '30px'}}>
       <span ref={textRef}></span>
    </Description>
  </Box>
)
```

Currently I have a problem where if I click on the animation while the first is already playing, it will play the second one. I would like to disable the onClick property if possible for the duration of the animation, or alternatively prevent the function which starts up the animation again from running while the animation is already in play

EDIT:

I would like to add that I can't use `useState` with some `[busy, setBusy]` as it rerenders the page

Answer (score 0):

you could define a state to handle disable/enable the button

```
const [isDisabledBtn, setIsDisabledBtn] = useState(false);

const typedFun = async () {
  setIsDisabledBtn(true);
  typedCaller2();
  const waitFor = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
  await waitFor(1000).then(() => typedCaller3());
  setIsDisabledBtn(false);
}
```

Comment: I can't do that as it would re render the whole page, breaking functionality of other components

Comment: use could move this button to separate component, so it just re-render child component